# udhcpc: How can I get the result of requesting option?

Tags: linux, dhcp, busybox

I use commond line like this:

```
udhcpc -O domain
```

But the teminal only shows like this:

```
Sending discover...
Sending select for 192.168.X.X...
Lease of 192.168.X.X obtained, leasing time ...
```

So where is my requesting result?

Comment: Btw, there's really no point in obscuring a private 192.168.x.x IP address.

Comment: That is not the key point. I want to know the dhcp option result.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Answer (score 5):

All results from the DHCP reply are passed to the hook script, by default located in `/usr/share/udhcpc/default.script` and `/usr/share/udhcpc/default.script.d`, respectively. The options are either available by their name (like `$domain`) in which case they are converted to the correct format by udhcpc (like a string or IP address), or by their number (`$opt224`) for unknown options, in which case they are simply hexdumps of the option.

So if you only want to know the returned option, place a script like the following at `/usr/share/udhcpc/default.script.d/echo-domain`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Domain: $domain"
```

Comment: +1 Welcome to SU and interesting answer, I learned something :-) By the way, you might want to add a cautionary note to remove this script again after troubleshooting is over :-)

Comment: It doesn't do any harm leaving the script in place, as it is executed in addition to the usual actions udhcpc takes (in `/usr/share/udhcpc/default.script`).

Comment: @jplitza "by their number ($opt224) for unknown options, in which case they are simply hexdumps of the option."
Where is this feature documented?

Comment: @DrP3pp3r Nowhere, I found out via a script that piped `env` to a file.